# "I hope he tells" vs. "I hope he will tell"

Tags: present-tense, future-time

I saw these two phrase and I was wondering which one is correct?

> 1. I hope he tells me the truth
> 2. I hope he will tell me the truth

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

> I hope he will tell me the truth.

"he will tell me" is future tense.

> I hope he tells me the truth.

"he tells me" is present tense, however in the context of the phrase with "I hope" it implies the future.